# android get value of HashMap array

Tags: java, android, hashmap, key-value

Im trying to get value of Hashmap array but im getting index/key.

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

Code how i get values from parser

```
 HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
map.put(KEY_LAT, parser.getValue(e, KEY_LAT));
map.put(KEY_LON, parser.getValue(e, KEY_LON));
map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));
menuItems.add(map);
```

Then i try get values but i receive index.

```
for (int i = 0; i < menuItems.size(); i++){
        int latitude = Integer.parseInt(KEY_LAT);
        int longitude = Integer.parseInt(KEY_LON);
        itemizedOverlay.addOverlayItem(latitude, longitude, KEY_NAME, makerDefault);
    }
```

How to get value from menuItems array ?
In other activity i get values but there is used through TextView. Is there other way ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (Map<String, String> menuItem : menuItems) {
    int latitude = Integer.parseInt(menuItem.get(KEY_LAT));
    int longitude = Integer.parseInt(menuItem.get(KEY_LON));
    itemizedOverlay.addOverlayItem(latitude, longitude, KEY_NAME, makerDefault);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterating through the Array is best done like this:

```
for (HashMap map: menuItems) {
}
```

then you can access the map itself:

```
for (HashMap map: menuItems) {
    String value = map.get(key);
}
```